# Can I use prepositions 'in' and 'for' interchangebly in this context?

Tags: prepositions, for

Question:

> **Which option is right. In case if both are right- for which case the using is more appropriate or *I can use them interchangeably in some cases*?**

.

> 1) **IN** or/and **FOR**

1. I haven't seen him **in a few** years
2. I haven't seen him **for a few** years

> 2) **IN** or/and **FOR**

1. I haven't seen him **in a seven** years
2. I haven't seen him **for a seven** years

Comment: Personally, I think [*They have not worked **in** years*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+worked+in+years%2Cnot+worked+for+years&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20worked%20in%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20worked%20for%20years%3B%2Cc0) sounds a bit "quaint, folksy", but it's been gaining traction in recent decades. Bottom line - it's *always* at least *possible* to use ***for***, but ***in*** doesn't work at all in non-negated contexts such as *He's been seeing her once a week for years.*

Comment: @stangdon Thanks for your concern. Pretty close but _I want to know if I can use them interchangeably in some cases_

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are correct and interchangeable:

> I haven't seen him in a few years.
>   I haven't seen him for a few years.

The article 'a' is not correct in these sentences:

> I haven't seen him in a seven years
>   I haven't seen him for a seven years

'A few' is an idiom, unlike 'seven', which is a precise number of years and doesn't require the article.

The following sentences are correct:

> I haven't seen him in seven years.
>   I haven't seen him for seven years.

Personally, I prefer "in a" in these scenarios but there is nothing wrong with "for a".